# __getattr__ for static/class variables

Tags: python, class-method, getattr

I have a class like:

```
class MyClass:
     Foo = 1
     Bar = 2
```

Whenever `MyClass.Foo` or `MyClass.Bar` is invoked, I need a custom method to be invoked before the value is returned. Is it possible in Python? I know it is possible if I create an instance of the class and I can define my own `__getattr__` method. But my scnenario involves using this class as such without creating any instance of it.

Also I need a custom `__str__` method to be invoked when `str(MyClass.Foo)` is invoked. Does Python provide such an option?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`__getattr__()` and `__str__()` for an object are found on its class, so if you want to customize those things for a class, you need the class-of-a-class. A metaclass.

```
class FooType(type):
    def _foo_func(cls):
        return 'foo!'

    def _bar_func(cls):
        return 'bar!'

    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        if key == 'Foo':
            return cls._foo_func()
        elif key == 'Bar':
            return cls._bar_func()
        raise AttributeError(key)

    def __str__(cls):
        return 'custom str for %s' % (cls.__name__,)

class MyClass(metaclass=FooType):
    pass

# # in python 2:
# class MyClass:
#    __metaclass__ = FooType


print(MyClass.Foo)
print(MyClass.Bar)
print(str(MyClass))
```

printing:

```
foo!
bar!
custom str for MyClass
```

And no, an object can't intercept a request for a stringifying one of its attributes. The object returned for the attribute must define its own `__str__()` behavior.

**Updated** 2023-02-20 for Python 3.x default implementation (python 2 as a comment).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio and Matt. I think now I understand how class (not instance) creation works and also I thought the required __str__ behaviour was difficult to achieve. I think metaclasses should be good enough for my requirement. :)

Comment: If you always get `AttributeError` check out the other answer, which has the syntax for python3 (this example seems to be python2)

Comment: @Chris: This basic idea in the code works in Python 3. Aside from the `print` statements, the only thing that needs to be changed is how the metaclass is specified (as mentioned is a comment in it now).

Comment: What does the panel think about editing this answer to lead with the python 3 syntax, and reducing the python 2 to a comment?  I'm happy to make the edit.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Done. I have many posts I probably should update. It was a very different Python 13 years ago.

Answer (score 23):

(I know this is an old question, but since all the other answers use a metaclass...)

You can use the following simple `classproperty` descriptor:

```
class classproperty(object):
    """ @classmethod+@property """
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = classmethod(f)
    def __get__(self, *a):
        return self.f.__get__(*a)()
```

Use it like:

```
class MyClass(object):

     @classproperty
     def Foo(cls):
        do_something()
        return 1

     @classproperty
     def Bar(cls):
        do_something_else()
        return 2
```

Comment: This will only help if you know the names of your properties beforehand. If you read them from file and need to react dynamically, this will not work.

Comment: It could still work in theory -- read them from a file, and in a for-loop call `setattr(MyClass, prop_name, classproperty(..., ...))`

Answer (score 13):

For the first, you'll need to create a metaclass, and define `__getattr__()` on that.

```
class MyMetaclass(type):
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return '%s result' % name

class MyClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = MyMetaclass

print MyClass.Foo
```

For the second, no. Calling `str(MyClass.Foo)` invokes `MyClass.Foo.__str__()`, so you'll need to return an appropriate type for `MyClass.Foo`.

Comment: Tested this example and it only works for me in Python 2.x.  After changing the print to a function, Python 3.2 gives me a "AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'Foo'" error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @CyberED: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses : "When the class definition is read, if a callable `metaclass` keyword argument is passed after the bases in the class definition, the callable given will be called instead of `type()`."

Comment: Couldn't wait .... after a bit of Googling and testing :

The example is for Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x you need :

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass):
    pass

Answer (score 9):

Surprised no one pointed this one out:

```
class FooType(type):
    @property
    def Foo(cls):
        return "foo!"

    @property
    def Bar(cls):
        return "bar!"

class MyClass(metaclass=FooType):
    pass
```

Works:

```
>>> MyClass.Foo
'foo!'
>>> MyClass.Bar
'bar!'
```

(for Python 2.x, change definition of `MyClass` to:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooType
```

)

What the other answers say about `str` holds true for this solution: It must be implemented on the type actually returned.

Comment: While I usually try to refrain from posting "Thanks", I seriously need to post "Thanks" right now: Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155436/getattr-for-static-class-variables#comment76327249_22729414) under a different properties-like answer, this is only feasible if you know the name of the properties in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the case I use this pattern

```
class _TheRealClass:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
       pass

LooksLikeAClass = _TheRealClass()
```

Then you import and use it.

```
from foo import LooksLikeAClass
LooksLikeAClass.some_attribute
```

This avoid use of metaclass, and handle some use cases.