# Static class attributes with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods

I need to define custom attributes for a class, but redefining `__getattr__` works only for the instance, not for the class itself, and making it static doesn't really help. I know that something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3155493/) works for Python 2, but I couldn't find anything similar on Python 3, I suspect due to changing the way metaclasses work. How would I achieve similar result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the way you specify metaclasses in Python 3. It was changed from a dunder attribute `__metaclass__` to a `kwarg` you supply after the base classes. Other than that, the solution provided there suffices:

```
class MyClass(metaclass = FooType): pass
```

Now `MyClass.Foo` or `MyClass.Bar` call the methods `_foo_func` and `_bar_func` respectively.

Note that the custom descriptor object, the second answer in the linked question, is:

1. More portable granted you explicitly inherit from `object` in your class definitions.
2. More maintainable than creating a custom metaclass. Metaclasses might lead to confusion and weird conflicts down the line, descriptors are simple after you get a hang of them

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jims answer: If you need Python2 and 3 compatibility you can use the [`six.add_metaclass`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.add_metaclass) class decorator:

```
import six

@six.add_metaclass(your_metaclass)
class Yourclass():  # no need to add "metaclass = your_metaclass" here!
    # no need to define "__metaclass__ = your_metaclass" here
```

Like the documentation states, this:

```
@six.add_metaclass(Meta)
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

is identical to (python2):

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

or (python3):

```
class MyClass(object, metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```