# Python get arbitrary static method with magic method

Tags: python

I have a class `A` with many static methods (`a`, `b`, `c`...`z`):

```py
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def a():
    return 1
  ...
```

I would like to also have a "catch all" magic method such that when I call a property of `A` that doesn't exist, and perform some function.

---

I tried:

```
@staticmethod
def __getattr__(cls, item):
  raise Exception("fallback")
```

and

```
def fallback(cls, item):
  raise Exception("fallback")

A.__getattr__ = fallback
```

But when I try to access, for example `A.aa`, I get an error:

> AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'aa'

Comment: You would want to do this with metaclasses

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3155436/3001761