# How I can call method using value from variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

I want to call an undefined method, but it is defined in Pyro Daemon.
For example, we have the class `Sender` without method `publish`, and I used `__getattr__` for call undefined method.

For example:

```py
class Sender:
    ...
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            def method(*args):
                """
                for example name = publish and I want to call method self.proxy.publish
                """
                self.call_if_connected(lambda: self.proxy.name(args))
            return method

Sender.publish()
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_getattr\_\_ for static/class variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155436/getattr-for-static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: Not really (   
when I got name, I want to call the method which this name
if name = publish, I want to call method publish, not name

Answer (score 0):

I found answer

```
result = eval("self.proxy." + name + "(args)")
```

so when I called undefined method, that goes to getattr and after call right method